# Greater than comparison for strings in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

First off, I don't have any controll over the database so I can't change anything there.

The field in the database is a varchar(50) and contains (for the records I'm interested in) a number. I'd like to get all of them with a number over 50. In SQL I just type:

```
SELECT Field FROM MyTable WHERE Field > '50'
```

That works fine even though I can agree the datatype should be something else.

In EF I'm trying:

```
query = query.Where(t => t.MyTable.Field > string);
```

There error is: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the data in the `Field` is always of numeric type?

Comment: _'for the records I'm interested in'_ doesn't look like it.

Comment: You cannot do this in EF. Why do you use varchar for numbers instead of numeric types?

Comment: Have you tried `query = query.Where(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.MyTable.Field) > int);` ?

Comment: string comparisons of numeric data sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @unlimit Yes, for the selections I'm working with. I know there is a number in the field. What is the problem here guys? The ASCII value of 50 will always be lower than 55. So why all the downvotes on the question and answers?

As you can see in my question, I have absolutely no control over the DB and I'm trying to solve a problem without reading the whole db into memory. Yes, I also have some issues with having a number stored as a varchar, but there might be reasons for this that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score -3):

use int.Parse(str) C# is not implicitly typed - ergo you have to convert it to an integer, double etc befoe using the '>' operator. If you are not sure if the string will be a number then you can use int.tryparse(str)

Answer (score -3):

Originally, I suggested the below code, which I tried and worked but not using EF entity set:

```
query = query.Where(t => int.TryParse(t.Mytable.Field, out number) && int.Parse(t.MyTable.Field) > int.Parse(string));
```

And then, after getting some good comments, I tried it on EF set, and that line itself worked, but after that line executes, I tried to so anything on the results of the query above (e.g. Count()), I got the below exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean TryParse(System.String, Int32  ByRef)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: I beg to differ, all it is a string value - therefore you can cast it to anything you like. it certainly works in my code

Comment: If it wasn't then there's no way it'd compile, unless it was.

Comment: It works for me, just tried it. I just ran the following code:

            class MyObject { public string Id { get; set; } }
            int n;
            var q = _objects.Where(o => int.TryParse(o.Id, out n) && int.Parse(o.Id) > 0);

Comment: int.Parse() cannot be transfered to SQL query, so when you try to get real data from db - it fails.

Comment: @Krill I tried it more in depth, and I see what happens now, thanks... I updated my answer.